# WD Sentinel DX 4000 Remote Web Access requires port blocked by ISP. Is it possible to change the default ports?

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, iis, ssl, http, storage

WD Sentinel DX 4000 Remote Web Access requires port blocked by ISP.  Is it possible to change the default ports?

The ports required are 80 for HTTP, and 443 for HTTPS.

I can RDP into the server behind Western Digital's front end (itself apparently just an IIS web page presented through RDP), but wouldn't know where to begin to look to modify the default ports.  I've been told it's possible, but even that, I'm not certain of.

I'm not, as I'm sure you can tell, any kind of professional admin.  I'm just the guy that isn't scared of computers in my office, so I get these things tasked to me.

Comment: Are you sure you're on a business-class ISP service?

Comment: Yes.  The ISP uses a proxy filter for morality filtering which includes blocking ports they feel are likely to be useful to "hackers".  This is country wide, and a matter of law, not a matter of service options or other optional possibilities.

Answer (score 1):

Ports 80 and 443 are blocked by your ISP?  Time to get a new ISP.  It doesn't appear you can change the ports used on this WSS device that I can see.

How do you know they are being blocked at the ISP level?  It's more likely that there's a firewall at your location (possibly inside the WAN router or cable modem, or whatever is at your SMB) that you need to setup to allow 80 and 443 port forwarding through your WAN firewall into the WD Sentinel.

Do you have a firewall in between the DX4000 and the ISP?  You could setup the rules there using PAT (port address translation) to do something like `external_IP:88 redirects to DX4000_internalIP:80`.  However, it may get tricky if it doesn't also allow for `external_IP:444 redirects to DX4000_internalIP:443` or requires both http and https during the connections.  You might only need the SSL (2nd PAT) one if your users can go straight to that link.

Short of that, the only option I can think of is setting up a separate VPN than the built-in remote web access one on the DX4000 (either through the WAN firewall router or on a separate VPN server) that would get the users remote access into the network where they can directly access the DX4000.

Comment: The ISP lists them as blocked, and the WD DX4000 lists this as one of the possible problems if Web Access will not work.  I live in the Middle East.  Getting a new ISP is not a solution, short of moving to Europe or back to the USA.

Comment: @zenbike - updated my answer then...see again.

Comment: There is no seperate hardware firewall.

Comment: The WD DX4000 is directly connected to the ISP?

Comment: There is a standard Linksys EA6700 router, and the fiber modem that is the ISP connection.  There is a firewall built in to the router, but no additional seperate firewall.

Comment: There you go.  Look in the manual on page 43 `Port Forwarding and Port Triggering` for the EA6700.  That will guide you through setting up what I'm talking about in the "Do you have a firewall in between the DX4000 and the ISP?" paragraph.